# Slide some columns by 1 and insert new value

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a table that looks like this:

| fname | lname | y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 | y5 | y6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1B | 5 | 6 | 4 |  |  |  |
| C | 2D | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| E | 3F |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| G | 4H | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| I | 5J | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |

I am iterating over the rows and checking a condition, if the condition is met (e.g. for every odd row), add a lowerase of column fname to column y1 and slide the current y1 to y2. As a result, the output table becomes:

| fname | lname | y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 | y5 | y6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1B | a | 5 | 6 | 4 |  |  |
| C | 2D | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| E | 3F | e |  |  |  |  |  |
| G | 4H | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| I | 5J | i | 7 |  |  |  |  |

My major concern is how to slide the y columns only by 1 and insert a new value.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in for loop

```
lower = df.fname.str.lower()
df = df.set_index(['fname','lname'])

l = [[y]+x if z%2 == 0 else x for x , y , z in zip(df.values.tolist(),lower,np.arange(len(df)))]
newdf = pd.DataFrame(l,index=df.index).reset_index()
newdf
fname lname    0    1    2    3   4   5   6
0     A    1B    a  5.0  6.0  4.0 NaN NaN NaN
1     C    2D  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2     E    3F    e  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
3     G    4H  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
4     I    5J    i  7.0  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```